# Query doesn't show table1 row which id is not in table2 using inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table,

```
table1
=======================================
pid    pname           coldate      col4
---------------------------------------
1      Tesitng Name1   2019-01-01    self
2      Tesitng Name2   2020-01-01    self
3      Tesitng Name3   2020-03-01    self2
4      Tesitng Name4   2020-04-04    self2
5      Tesitng Name5   2020-04-05    self3
```

in table1 pid have unique key

```
table2 //which have more than 600k rows
=======================================
billid   rate            pid
---------------------------------------
1        30               1
2        50               1
3        40               1
4        10               3
```

///In table2 billid have unique key

I try to show all rows of table1 with sum of rate column of table2 where table1.pid=table2.pid

Result shoul be like this

```
   table1
    =======================================================
    pid    pname           coldate       col4     total
    -------------------------------------------------------
    1      Tesitng Name1   2019-01-01    self      120
    2      Tesitng Name2   2020-01-01    self       0
```

I am using this query

```
    SELECT 
    t1.*
    , ttl.total
FROM table1 t1 
    inner join 
        (SELECT pid, sum(rate) as total
        FROM table2 
        GROUP BY pid) as ttl
            on ttl.pid=t1.pid
WHERE 
    t1.coldate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-04-01'
    AND t1.col4 = 'self' 
ORDER BY t1.pid DESC;
```

but it doesn't show table1 row which pid is not in table2 
please tell me the fastest way to perform this action
I am using php with mysql..

Comment: "It doesn't show table1 row which pid is not in table2".  You don't query for that.  How do you expect to get that???

Comment: And if you want rows in table1 which pid is not in table2, what's the point if `ttl.total`?  It will always be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Your title says it all, as if you know you need a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.*, ttl.total
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT pid, sum(rate) as total
      FROM table2 
      GROUP BY pid
     ) ttl
     ON ttl.pid = t1.pid
WHERE t1.coldate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-04-01' AND
      t1.col4 = 'self' 
ORDER BY t1.pid DESC;
```

For performance, you should probably use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       (SELECT SUM(tt1.rate)
        FROM table2 tt1
        WHERE ttl.pid = t1.pid
       ) total
FROM table1 t1 
WHERE t1.coldate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-04-01' AND
      t1.col4 = 'self' 
ORDER BY t1.pid DESC;
```

Then you want indexes on `table1(col4, coldate, pid)` and `table2(pid, rate)`.

Comment: it says:Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'pid'

Comment: it taking to much time comparison to my query provided above

Answer (score 0):

You have in your subquery already a bug , you have to remove the second pid like in the xample below.

To get all rows from table1 you need a LEFT JOIN instead of a INNER JOIN

But your Where clause reduces everything to 1 row anyway.

```
    SELECT 
    t1.*
    , ttl.total
FROM table1 t1 
    LEFT join 
        (SELECT pid, sum(rate) as total
        FROM table2 
        GROUP BY pid) as ttl
            on ttl.pid=t1.pid
WHERE 
    t1.coldate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-04-01'
    AND t1.col4 = 'self' 
ORDER BY t1.pid DESC;
```